# MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $and

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this query code but having problem making it work. I am using NodeJS and database is mongoDB.

```
  Transducer.find({$and: [{isNew:{$eq:true}}, {isPublished:{$eq:true}}]})
    .sort({"nominalDiameterin":1})
    .limit(50)
    .exec(function(err, allTransducers){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        if(req.xhr) {
            res.json(allTransducers);
        } else {
            var id = req.params.id;
            if(id === 'en'){
                res.render("products/transducers", {transducers: allTransducers, length: allTransducers.length});
            }else if(id === 'cn'){
                res.render("products/transducers-cn", {transducers: allTransducers, length: allTransducers.length});
            }

        }
```

I want to display data that are new and published but I having no luck.

Any help, please?

Comment: You actually not need the `$and` anyway. ALL MongoDB query arguments are already AND conditions. `.find({ 'isNew': true, 'isPublished': true })`. Same goes for `$eq`. It's all implied. That's what makes it nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear @Vina Vanessa Compson u can no need to use $and and $eq operator for simple query and your syntax is also incorrect .

Please follow below answer

```
var query = {
        isNew:true,
        isPublished:true
  }

  var toSort = {
    nominalDiameterin:1
}
  Transducer.find(query).sort(toSort).limit(50).exec(function(err, allTransducers) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      if(req.xhr) {
        res.json(allTransducers);
      } else {
        var id = req.params.id;
        if(id === 'en'){
          res.render("products/transducers", {transducers: allTransducers, length: allTransducers.length});
        }else if(id === 'cn'){
          res.render("products/transducers-cn", {transducers: allTransducers, length: allTransducers.length});
        }

      }
    }
  })
```